# ARMA model in R

Tags: r, time-series, arma

I am a bit confused using the `arma()` function in R regarding interpretation.  So what exactly is the equation of a for example AR(1,0,2) given the output AR1, MA1, MA2 and intercept in R?

Comment: Assuming you refer to function `arima` in the `stats`package, the equation of the ARMA model is given in the documentation: $X[t] = a[1]X[t-1] + \dots + a[p]X[t-p] + e[t] + b[1]e[t-1] + \dots + b[q]e[t-q]$. The $a$-s are the AR coefficients and the $b$-s the MA coefficients shown in the output. The parameter labelled as "intercept" in the output is actually the estimated mean of the input data.

Comment: And if I add exogenous regressors do I also need to transform it?

Comment: Do you mean if you should take differences? If so, no, you don't need to take differences on the exogenous regressors, it is done by `arima`if the model contains a differencing order higher than zero.